# How can i save data using android version 9

Tags: java, save

I have a problem with my application. it works very well on all Android versions except version 9, SDK 28.
I am sending a data form to a PHP file on a web server.
I use java.
Here are my codes

```
tringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, ServerURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map <String,String> Params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Params.put("Compte","123");
                Params.put("Nom", "Silver");
                return Params;
            }
        };
        Mysingleton2.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addTorequestque(stringRequest);
```

I use Android studio, compileSdkVersion 28, minSdkVersion 21, targetSdkVersion 28.
When I do the recording on all versions, everything goes well except on the Android 9 version.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help us help you, could you mention some more details? What does not go well on Android 9? Are you getting an error? If yes, what does the error say? What other versions have you tried?